# jqgrid virtual scrolling doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Good day to you.
I am trying to embed a jqGrid table in some system, but encountered an error, that prevents me from going further.
I tried to find a post with a similar problem but didn't succeed. 
If there is post that solves this - please refer me to it.

The problem - 
There is no event fired when scrolling beneath the last row shown.

Please take a look.

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <base href="XXXX"/>
    <title>Table</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="outside">
        <div id="header">
        </div><!-- end of header -->


        <div id="topright">
            <h3>Main menu</h3>

        </div><!-- end of topright -->

        <div id="break"></div>

        <div id="left">
            <div id="nav">
                <h3>Navigation</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                                            <li>
                        <a href="sitetrack"><strong>Hunting</strong></a>
                    </li>





                                            <li><a href="/players">Players</a></li>

                                            <li><a href="/status">Status</a></li>

                                            <li><a href="management">Management</a></li>

                                            <li><a href="/tools">Tools</a> <strong style="color: red; font-weight bold">NEW!</strong></li>

                    <li><a href="/logout">Log out</a></li> 
                </ul>
                <h3>Information</h3>
                                    <p>You are logged in as <strong></strong></p>
                <p style="font-size: 7pt">Access privileges:
                    <ul>
                        <li style="font-size: 6pt">system_administrator</li>
                    </ul>
                </p>

            </div><!-- end of nav -->
        </div><!-- end of left -->


        <div id="main">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="bo_admin/libs/jquery-ui/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bo_admin/libs/jQGrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bo_admin/css/menu.css">

<style>
    .ui-priority-secondary {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 gainsboro;
    }
</style>

<script src="bo_admin/libs/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="bo_admin/libs/jQGrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="bo_admin/libs/jQGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

(function ($) {

    $(function () {
        initGrid();
    });

function initGrid() {
    var options = {

        mtype:"GET",
        url: "XXXX/inbotablefeed?reportName=v_BO_big_ret",
        datatype: "json",
        height: "350",

        colNames: ['X', 'X', 'X',...,'X'],
        colModel: [{}, {}, {}],

        caption: "Bo Admin",
        altRows: false,
        width:1500,
        autowidth: false,
        scroll:true,
        prmNames: { npage: 'npage' },
        pager: $('#pager'),
        sortname: 'invdata',
        rownumbers: true,
        forceFit: false,

        shrinkToFit: false,
        viewrecords: true
    };

    $("#grid")
        .jqGrid(options)

        .navGrid(
            '#pager', 
            {
                edit: false,
                add: false,
                del: false
            },
            {}, 
            {}, 
            {}, 
            {
                multipleSearch:true, 
                multipleGroup:true
            }
        )

        .filterToolbar({
            stringResult: true,
            searchOnEnter: true
        });
    }

})(jQuery);

</script>
    <div style="position:fixed;">
           <ul id="menu">
            <li>
                <a href="/botable">Users</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/botable?reportName=v_BO_big_ret">Big Retention</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/botable?reportName=v_BO_user_list">User list</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/botable">XXXX</a></li>
            <li><a href="/botable">XXXXX</a></li>
            <li><a href="/botable">XXXX</a></li>
            <li><a href="/botable">XXX</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
            <div style="position:absolute; top: 120px;">
            <table id="grid"></table>
            <div id="pager"></div>
    </div>






        </div><!-- end of main -->


        <div id="bottombreak"></div>

        <div id="footer">
            (C) XXXXXX
        </div><!-- end of footer -->


    </div><!-- end of outside -->
```

Comment: I saw that someone minused this question... I am new to the stackoverflow and to the developers world. If this isn't appropriate question - please tell me why...